# Enable hotswap into Spring boot embedded server

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hotswap

Can hotswap be enabled using Spring boot ? When deploying Spring projects with Tomcat server setup separately hotswap seems enabled by default. But with Spring boot apps hotswap does not appear to be enabled. Is there a config can update hot swapping code into embedded Spring boot server ?

Comment: I might be missing something here, but if Tomcat is embedded in your application, what do you intend to hot swap? Surely whatever you plan on distribute will involve a new instance of Tomcat?

Comment: @DaveyDaveDave intend to hotswap changes as the app is being worked on, prior to distribution.

Comment: you may like [spring boot 1.3 devtools](https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/17/devtools-in-spring-boot-1-3). for your hotswap

Answer (score 0):

Use this dependencies

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

If you using Intellij IDEA right click to file you changed and click "Compile and Reload File"

Answer (score -1):

Looking at effective pom of Spring boot this is included :

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>springloaded</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.4.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
```

Which enables hot swapping.

Should not need to configure a java agent to enable hot swapping.

Fix for me is to just start app in debug mode instead of 'run' mode. This forces re-compilation on src changes.